# which scripture says "parokshakama hi devah", and what does it mean?‘

Tags: scripture, gods

Does it mean the Gods have caused scriptures to be composed in a way that they are hard to understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is "parokshapriya iva hi devah" then it's from the Aitreya Upanishad. Quoting from page 14 of [this PDF](https://esamskriti.com/essays/Aitareya-Upanishad.pdf):

> tasmAdidandro nAmedandro ha vai nAma . tamidandra.n santami.ndra
> ityAchakShate parokSheNa . **parokShapriyA iva hi devAH parokShapriyA
> iva hi devAH** .. 14.
>
> Therefore  He  is  called  Idandra.  Idandra,  indeed  is  His  name.
> Him  who  is  Idandra  they  call  indirectly  Indra.  For  the  gods
> appear  to  be  fond  of  cryptic  epithets;  yea,  the gods appear to
> be fond of cryptic epithets (paroksha priyaahi iva devah).

It basically means Gods love to be mysterious and veiled and do not want themselves to be revealed.

Quoting an alternate translation from [this page](https://upanishads.org.in/upanishads/8/3/14):

> tasmādidandro nāmedandro ha vai nāma | tamidandraṁ santamiṁdra
> ityācakṣate parokṣeṇa | parokṣapriyā iva hi devāḥ parokṣapriyā iva hi
> devāḥ || Anvaya
>
> तस्मात् इदन्द्रः ह वै नाम इदन्द्रः। इदन्द्रं सन्तं तं परोक्षेण इन्द्रः
> इति आचक्षते। हि देवाः परोक्षप्रियाः इव ॥
>
> tasmāt idandraḥ ha vai nāma idandraḥ| idandraṁ santaṁ taṁ parokṣeṇa
> indraḥ iti ācakṣate| hi devāḥ parokṣapriyāḥ iva || Meaning
>
> Therefore is He Idandra; for Idandra is the true name of Him. But
> though He is Idandra, they call Him Indra because of the veil of the
> Unrevelation; for the gods love the veil of the Unrevelation, yea,
> verily, the gods love the Unrevelation.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, @rickross